# Bootstrap unequal column creation

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a website in `bootstrap`. I need to make a right hand side column makes a big serial number 4. When I fill the column height make the big simultaneously space is come out the between the serial no 3 and 6.

How can I solve the problem?

```
<div class="col-md-3">content goes here</div>
<div class="col-md-3">content</div>
<div class="col-md-3">content</div>
<div class="col-md-3">BIG COLUM</div>
<div class="col-md-3">content</div>
<div class="col-md-3">content</div>
<div class="col-md-3">content</div>
```

[Example](http://sbct.in/test5/test5.html)

Answer (score 0):

The only other thing I can think of is to use: on your vertical column. Check out this link http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options
Check out the offset column section as well.

Answer (score -1):

Remember to wrap your page in a `<div class="container"`, then wrap it in a `<div class="row"`... also remember that the grid width is only 12 wide, so you have to many divs as col-md-3, you can use only four.

Comment: yes my first row only four columns "col-md-3". I am try to make last column make bigger <div class="col-md-3">BIG COLUM</div>. Then second row make a three column + first last column cover the second row side also. ref link is above